# hitTest boundingBoxOnly not work for SCNPlane

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

In my app I want to add a SCNPlane to rootNode.

It's a simple node with layer that has a border. (just a box with a transparent body)

```
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: WIDTH, height: WIDTH*heigh/width)
    layer.backgroundColor =  UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 150, blue: 255, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 10
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

let scene = SCNPlane(width: width, height: heigh)
    scene.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = false
    scene.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = layer
    geometry    = scene
```

**I want to prevent SCNPlanes overlap.**

So I tried this:

```
let results = sceneView.hitTest(point, options: [.boundingBoxOnly : true])
guard (result.node as? ViewNode) == nil else { return }
```

**But I found out it only works at the edge of the node.**

Please help me.

How can i use hitTest to know if this position has this kind of node?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the reason .

turn off debug model ,every thing works fine

```
//        sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
```